# Can webpack compile .jsx inside node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules, babel-loader

I created a shared repo of components and helper functions on github.

I import it as a node_module inside my React project.

```
$ yarn add git+ssh.../my_shared_stuffs

import OneComponent from "my_shared_stuffs/OneComponent"
```

Works fine with scss and functions but I got error on .jsx elements:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
```

Some SyntaxError around every div, Component, ...

In my webpack config i tried something like :

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    use: ['babel-loader'],
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
      path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/my_shared_stuffs")
    ]
  },
```

Anything wrong with that?

my .babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "react-loadable/babel",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-property-literals",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you provide the github repo you mentioned?

Comment: nope, but this happens on normal react components, nothing special

Comment: or tell a bit more about how did you import your shared stuff

Comment: $ yarn add git+ssh.../my_shared_stuffs

Answer (score 1):

In case it can helps, here's a solution in webpack config:

```
const babelSettings = {
  extends: path.join(__dirname, "./.babelrc")
};
```

...

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: ["babel-loader?" + JSON.stringify(babelSettings)],
```